# Как с помощью ползунков input type="range" равномерно распределить значение между ними?

Tags: javascript, html

Друзья !!! Несколько дней уже пытаюсь победить эту проблему ,но ни что не помогает ! У меня есть главный инпут с основным значением . Мне надо с помощью трех ползунков range  равномерно распределить это значение по инпутам рядом с ползунками. Соответственно при изменении ползунком основное число должно уменьшаться ! 
ВСЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЯ ДОЛЖНЫ БЫТЬ ЦЕЛЫМИ ЧИСЛАМИ ! И STEP у range должен быть равен 10

```js
var mainInput = document.getElementById('mainInput');

var firstRange = document.getElementById('firstRange');
var secondRange = document.getElementById('secondRange');
var thirdRange = document.getElementById('thirdRange');

var out1 = document.getElementById('out1');
var out2 = document.getElementById('out2');
var out3 = document.getElementById('out3');

var getFirstValue = function() {
  out1.value = this.value;

  mainInput.value = out1.value;
  var leftValue = 100 - mainInput.value;

  out2.value = out3.value = leftValue / 2;
}

var getSecondValue = function() {
  out2.value = this.value;

  mainInput.value = out2.value;
  var leftValue2 = 100 - mainInput.value;

  out1.value = out3.value = leftValue2 / 2;
}

var getThirdValue = function() {
  out3.value = this.value;

  mainInput.value = out3.value;
  var leftValue2 = 100 - mainInput.value;

  out1.value = out3.value = leftValue3 / 2;
}

firstRange.oninput = getFirstValue;
secondRange.oninput = getSecondValue;
thirdRange.oninput = getThirdValue;
```

```html
<h1>Распределитель</h1>
<label for="mainInput">Осталось распределить</label>
<input type="text" value="0" min="0" max="100" id="mainInput"><br>
<p><input type="range" id="firstRange"><input type="text" id="out1"></p>
<p><input type="range" id="secondRange"><input type="text" id="out2"></p>
<p><input type="range" id="thirdRange"><input type="text" id="out3"></p>
```

Comment: ничего непонятно

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял ТС, то - https://codepen.io/qwerty_wasd/pen/ERByea .
Есть ли у кого какие-нибудь идеи, как еще отрефакторить код?

```js
let formEvent = document.getElementById('formEvent'),
  mainInput = document.getElementById('mainInput'),
  firstRange = document.getElementById('firstRange'),
  secondRange = document.getElementById('secondRange'),
  thirdRange = document.getElementById('thirdRange'),
  out1 = document.getElementById('out1'),
  out2 = document.getElementById('out2'),
  out3 = document.getElementById('out3'),
  btClear = document.getElementById('btClear');
const spreadValue = e => {
    if (e.target === mainInput) {
      mainInput.max = firstRange.max = secondRange.max = thirdRange.max = e.target.value =
        (e.target.value < 10) ? 10 : (e.target.value > 100) ? 100 :
        (e.target.value >= 10 && e.target.value <= 100 && e.target.value % 10 == 0) ?
        e.target.value : (Math.round(e.target.value / 10)) * 10;
    }
    if ((e.target === firstRange || secondRange || thirdRange) && mainInput.value != 0) {
      mainInput.value = mainInput.max - firstRange.value - secondRange.value - thirdRange.value;
      out1.value = firstRange.value;
      out2.value = secondRange.value;
      out3.value = thirdRange.value;
    } else {
      mainInput.disabled = out1.disabled = out2.disabled = out3.disabled = firstRange.disabled = secondRange.disabled = thirdRange.disabled = true;
    }
  },
  clearForm = e => {
    mainInput.disabled = out1.disabled = out2.disabled = out3.disabled = firstRange.disabled = secondRange.disabled = thirdRange.disabled = false;
    out1.value = out2.value = out3.value = firstRange.value = secondRange.value = thirdRange.value = 0;
    mainInput.value = 100;
    e.preventDefault();
  };
btClear.addEventListener('click', clearForm);
formEvent.addEventListener('input', spreadValue);
window.onunload = () => {
  formEvent.removeEventListener('input', spreadValue);
  btClear.removeEventListener('click', clearForm);
}
```

```html
<form id="formEvent">
  <h1>Распределитель</h1>
  <label for="mainInput">Осталось распределить(шаг 10)</label>
  <input id="mainInput" type="text" value="100" min="0" max="100" />
  <p>
    <input id="firstRange" type="range" step="10" value="0" min="0" max="100" />
    <input id="out1" type="text" value="0" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input id="secondRange" type="range" step="10" value="0" min="0" max="100" />
    <input id="out2" type="text" value="0" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input id="thirdRange" type="range" step="10" value="0" min="0" max="100" />
    <input id="out3" type="text" value="0" />
  </p>
  <button id="btClear">Сбросить</button>
</form>
```